# Typescript nested dynamic properties

Tags: json, typescript, nested

I've been trying to improve the types of an older project that uses a lot of 'any' whenever things get complicated.

[Replit-link](https://replit.com/@acv98/NestedProblems#index.ts)

Consider the following irregular data structure where Data is an interface matching the example (some are nested objects, some are not. I use the same mapping function on all pages, depending on what is present in localData):

```
const data: Data = {
   car: { name: 'x', speed: 45},
   cat: { fur: true },
   random: ['hi', 'bye']
   why: "because"
};
```

Now I'm mapping this data on different pages like so

```
const nestedKey = 'car';
const localData = {
   name: '',
   speed: 0
};

Object.keys(localData).forEach(key => {
   if (nestedKey && data[nestedKey]) {
      // Here I'm not too sure what type to give key to make TS happy
      localData[key] = data[nestedKey as keyof Data][key]
   } else {
      localData[key] = data[key as keyof Data]
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`const nestedKey: keyof typeof data = 'car';`

`keyof typeof data` will return this literal type:

`'car' | 'cat' | 'random' | 'why'`

Which you could consume it like:

`localData[key] = data[nestedKey][key]`

Comment: 'Data' is already the type of the 'data' constant. Maybe my interface name was confusing. 
It complains about those nested types that they do not have index type to be matched by key string variable.
`No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'string | number | boolean | .... All possible types in my data`
One fix for this is to say `(data[nestedKey as keyof Data] as {[key: string]: any})[key]` 
But I was trying to avoid that any there and somehow get the keys of those nested objects with keyof keyof or something.

Comment: I also had a `typo` in the answer, it should be `const nestedKey: keyof typeof data = 'car'` ... `data` not `Data`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Plz be more specific about the problem you get ... "How" does that solution fail?

Comment: I already said what the errors are in my comment, maybe it's easier if you see them for yourself
https://replit.com/@acv98/NestedProblems#index.ts